# Is it possible to sort the fields returned in a document from ElasticSearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

Is it possible to sort the fields *inside* an ElasticSearch document when it is returned as part of a result set?

For example, I have the following document in my ElasticSearch instance:

```
doc : {
  "a":"45",
  "c":"35",
  "b":"43"
}
```

Is it possible to get the fields within doc to be sorted in alphabetical order?

```
doc : {
  "a":"45",
  "b":"43",
  "c":"35"
}
```

Just to be clear, I am not talking about sorting the result set, I'm talking about sorting the fields *within* each returned document.

I doubt it is possible as I don't think Json documents implicitly have an order. Maybe there's a way to get the client (Postman) to sort the data?

At the moment, I copy the document out of Postman and paste it into a text editor, flatten the indentation and then sort the document.

Comment: The only way is to "sort" the JSON before indexing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to specification http://json.org/

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs

Elasticsearch has no such functionality by default. You can take a look at [scripted fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) but it is usually better to do on application level.